# How to share data between 2 different API calls?

Tags: http, go, grpc-go

I am trying to create a framework in which I would receive requests over REST API and would wait for another service (which works over gRPC) to poll and execute the request. This is needed cause the "other" service is very deeply embedded into the network and I can't directly call it. At the same time, I would like to buffer the output of the other service back to the request origin.

Any ideas how I can share this data between 2 different asynchronous API requests? Using the file system is a way... but I was thinking can I do it better via channels or something...?

Comment: Does this work:  REST API endpoint makes synchronous call to other service and returns result to REST API client.

Comment: Not really... cause I cant call the other service... I need the other service to poll and pick up the request... and then send me the response which I need to stream back...

Comment: The service which receives the requests, dumps it into redis. The other service makes a grpc call and asks if any jobs are available... an agent queries redis and gives the job details to the other service.

Comment: It is not very clear how you are using the grpc service. Are you placing the payload from the incoming rest api call to some queue and the grpc service polls that queue?

Comment: Yes. I am using redis as the queue

Comment: And the grpc service places the response back in the redis queue?

Comment: Not yet... I was thinking my rest API could be getting multiple requests and if all the responses,from the other service, get stored in a queue it might get complicated to differentiate between the output...

Comment: Right now I am thinking of generating a uuid for each request and writing and reading from a file of that name... ?

Comment: But the incoming call expect a response back from the rest handler , so the rest handler need to do some polling while keeping the incoming call waiting until you have response. channel can be a good use case here

Comment: So something like I create a channel which is globally scoped. Now suppose I get 2 rest requests, and both the rest handlers are listening on the same channel. The rest handler should have a logic to identify if the chunk sent is for itself or not...?

Comment: I would say a channel per request.

Comment: How do I pass the channel around? Channel created by the rest handler... how does the other service know about the specific channel...

Comment: Use Redis queues in both directions. API endpoint writes request and unique id to queue, registers Go channel with unique id as key with central reader in process, and waits on Go channel (with timeout?).   Queue reader gets responses with id from Redis queue and sends response to appropriate Go channel.  If there are multiple processes running API endpoint,  then create Redis queue for each process and include id of the Redis queue in the request to the backend.

Comment: Submitted an answer as an idea

Comment: So in this approach each channel has the same name. The central reader is a function call. And each instance of the central reader reads the same queue for messages with unique id corresponding to it. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys... gave me nice perspective! Will try it out...

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Kind of pseudo code below:

```
func RestHandler(payload string) (string, error){
    respChan := make(chan string)
    workId := placeWorkInQueue(payload)
    // Start polling in the background
    go pollForResult(respChan, workId)
    // wait for result in the channel
    var result string
    select {
    case result = <-respChan:
        // implement your timeout logic as a another case: here
    }
    return result, nil
}

// This is poller for just the workId given to it.
func pollForResult(respChan chan string, workId string) {
    // Do the polling for workId result 
    /// Write response to respChan when available 
    // You may have to implement a timeout to give up polling.

}

func placeWorkInQueue(s string) string {
    // Place the job in queue and return a unique workId
    return "unique-id"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Redis queues in both directions. The API endpoint writes request and unique id to queue, registers Go channel with unique id as key with central reader in process, and waits on Go channel.

Queue reader gets responses with id from Redis queue and sends response to appropriate Go channel.

```
// Response represents the response type from the
// remote service.
type Response struct {
    ID string
    // ... more fields as needed
}

// Request represents request to remote serivce.
type Request struct {
    ID string
    // ... more fields as needed
}

// enqueueRequest writes request to Redis queue.
// Implementation TBD by application.
func enqueueRequest(r *Request) error {
    return nil
}

// dequeueResponse reads a response from a Redis queue.
// Implementation TBD by application.
func dequeueResponse() (*Response, error) {
    return nil, nil
}
```

Use sync.Map to register waiting Go channels from API request handlers. The key is the unique id for the request and the value is a `chan *Response`.

```
  var responseWaiters sync.Map
```

Run queuePump in a single goroutine to dequeue results from Redis queue and send to appropriate channel. Start the gorountine before serving HTTP requests.

```
func queuePump() {
    for {
        response, err := dequeueResponse()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        v, ok := responseWaiters.Load(response.ID)
        if ok {
            c := v.(chan *Response)
            c <- response

            // Remove cahnel from map to ensure that pump never sends 
            // twice to same channel. The pump will black forever if
            // this happens. 
            responseWaiters.Delete(response.ID)
        }
    }
}
```

The API endpoint allocates a unique id for request, registers a channel with the queue pump, enqueues the request and waits for the response.

```
func apiEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := generateUniqueID()

    c := make(chan *Response, 1) // capacity 1 ensures that queue pump will not block
    responseWaiters.Store(id, c)
    defer responseWaiters.Delete(id)

    req := &Request{
        ID: id,
        // fill in other fields as needed
    }

    if err := enqueueRequest(req); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    select {
    case resp := <-c:
        // process response
        fmt.Println(resp)
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        // handle timeout error
    }
}
```